# I have added custom fields to checkout page. Can't update_post_meta with them

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

I have added custom fields to the checkout page.
If the cart has more then 2 items in it, then the fields populate under billing.
For every other item in the cart, 3 more fields are generated.

The problem is the I cant save them to the post meta.

The first snipped prints them on the checkout page.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'person_details' );

function person_details($checkout) {
    global $woocommerce;
$count = $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count;
$i = 1;
       for($k=2; $k<= $count; $k++) {
        $i++;
           print ('<h4>Моля попълнете данни за участник '.$i.'</h4>');
        woocommerce_form_field( 'cstm_full_name'.$i, array(
            'type'          => 'text',
            'class'         => array('my-field-class form-row-wide'),
            'label'         => __('Две имена'),
            'placeholder'   => __(''),
            'required'      =>true,
            ),
            $checkout->get_value( 'cstm_full_name'.$i ));
        echo '<div class="clear"></div>';
        woocommerce_form_field( 'cstm_egn'.$i, array(
            'type'          => 'text',
            'class'         => array('my-field-class form-row-first'),
            'label'         => __('Длъжност'),
            'placeholder'   => __(''),
            'required'      =>true,
            ),
            $checkout->get_value( 'cstm_egn'.$i ));
        echo '<div class="clear"></div>';
        woocommerce_form_field( 'cstm_address'.$i, array(
            'type'          => 'textarea',
            'class'         => array('my-field-class form-row-wide'),
            'label'         => __('Имейл'),
            'placeholder'   => __(''),
            'required'      =>true,
            ),
            $checkout->get_value( 'cstm_address'.$i ));
}
}
```

The second should save them to the post meta:

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'customise_checkout_field_update_order_meta');

function customise_checkout_field_update_order_meta($order_id)
{
    global $woocommerce;
$count = $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count;
$i = 1;
       for($k=2; $k<= $count; $k++) {
        $i++;
    if (!empty($_POST['cstm_full_name'.$i])) {
        update_post_meta($order_id, 'Name of Attendee'.$i, sanitize_text_field($_POST['cstm_full_name'.$i]));
    }
    if (!empty($_POST['cstm_egn'.$i])) {
        update_post_meta($order_id, 'EGN of Attendee'.$i, sanitize_text_field($_POST['cstm_egn'.$i]));
    }
    if (!empty($_POST['cstm_address'.$i])) {
        update_post_meta($order_id, 'Address of Attendee'.$i, sanitize_text_field($_POST['cstm_address'.$i]));
    }
}
}
```

I have no clue how to proceed. So far I have changed bits of the code, but with no result.

Comment: I am unsure if the cart becomes empty on that saving hook or not. But if it becomes empty then you might not get anything from cart content and your for loop won't work. But if it doesn't become empty then it could be some other issue. However, Instead of using a count variable `$i` as a name use array type in the input name, you might need to write custom HTML if WooCommerce field functions don't support `field_name[]` as ID/name. then in the save function you can check POSTED field with `isset`  and loop it.

Comment: You are right. Checked database and there is no trace of those fields attached to orders. I will look into that. Thanks.